# Inspecting a variable in the lisp SLIME debugger

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to inspect the value of a variable at a determined breakpoint. Here is my simplified code:

```
(defun foo ()
  (maplist (lambda (var)
        (break)
        var)
      '(a b c)))
```

slime goes into debugger mode at this point. So I try to eval by pressing either the ":" or the "e" key and then I type "(car var)", but slime keeps on saying:

> The variable VAR is unbound.
>      [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

I am confused as to why it's saying this since "(break)" is within the anonymous function and within the scope of "var".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That works for me under CCL and CLisp. I think whether this works depends on your implementation, and maybe your `OPTIMIZE` settings. You could try:

```
(declaim (optimize (debug 3)))
```

You'll have to recompile your code afterwards for it to take effect.

Or maybe, if your implementation supports interpretation, you could try that, since some implementations provide better debugging possibilities for interpreted than for compiled code.

Comment: Also, of course you'd have to be in the right frame when pressing `e`, but I guess you know that, and that's where you end up by default anyway.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, thank you. Also, once you set the "(declaim (optimize (debug 3)))" line, you have to recompile your lisp code for the change to be effective. And yes, you have to be in the right frame when evaluating in the appropriate variable in the debugger.